# How to get text from a QLineEdit to update cells in a QTableView

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtableview

Overview: I have a UI that displays a `QTableView`. When the user clicks on a row in the table, the data from that row then populates several `QLineEdit` entry fields, corresponding to the information in that cell - for example the 'ADDRESS' column will have a corresponding 'ADDRESS' `QLineEdit` field where that address data will populate.

Existing Functionality: After clicking on a row, the user can click a `QLineEdit` and change the text listed - for example, if the wrong address was listed, the user could click on the 'ADDRESS' `QLineEdit` field and change it to something different.

Desired Functionality: I would like to be able to click a 'SAVE' button and have the data in the `QLineEdit`, then be reflected in the `QTableView`.

Problem: The function that runs when the 'SAVE' button is clicked, attempts to update the `QTableView` dataframe and refresh the view, but no changes appear to be made and the `QTableView` data itself, does not reflect any changes.

Code Examples:

**note - when the user clicks on the `QTableView`, a function runs which initializes the `self.user_selection` variable, which is a `QModelIndex` object and is referenced below. 
The `QLineEdit` fields are contained within a `QGridLayout`, hence the use of the `itemAtPosition` function below.
`self.comp_list` is the QTableView object that is being populated

When the user clicks on 'SAVE' the following function runs...

```
def update_selected_comp_entry(self):
    # This will get all of the values for each column, for the row selected - this returns a 
    # QWidgetItem, which is why widget().text() must be used to retrieve the cell's data
    items = [self.comp_details_layout.itemAtPosition(i, 1) for i in range(self.comp_details_layout.count()) if isinstance(comp_details_layout.itemAtPosition(i, 1), PyQt5.QtWidgets.QWidgetItem)]

    for i, each in enumerate(items):
        self.comp_list.model().setData(self.user_selection, each.widget().text())
```

A simplified version of my class that populates the `QTableView`:

```
class DataFrameModel(PyQt5.QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, df=pandas.DataFrame(), parent=None):
        super(DataFrameModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self._dataframe = df.replace(numpy.nan, '', regex=True)

    def setDataFrame(self, dataframe):
        self.beginResetModel()
        self._dataframe = dataframe.copy()
        self.endResetModel()

    # @PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSlot() - I've tried using this decorator and it didn't do anything
    # This function is my attempt at grabbing the user's input and updating 
    # the QTableView displayed data
    def setData(self, index, value, role=PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
        if index.isValid():
            row = index.row()
            col = index.column()

            # I've tried with and without the line below
            self.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit()
            # I've tried using set_value() as well as iloc and neither worked
            self._dataframe.loc[row, col] = value
            # I';ve tried with and without this line, neither worked
            self.setDataFrame(self._dataframe)
            # I've also tried the dataChanged signal and that didn't work either
            self.layoutChanged.emit()
            return True
        return False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't even bother with the `setData` function, there's no need for it based on what you have there. Since you're already getting all the data from the cells in your `items` variable, just use that to update the source from which you populated the `QTableView` in the first place. Since you know that method works, it'll take your updated data and you can refresh your table like you normally would.

For the sake of this example, let's assume your column headers are the same as what you had for your widget().objectName() would be for each of your QWidgetItem in your `items` variable. You can obviously change that to whatever you'd like.

You could make a dictionary with your column names as the keys and then the `QLineEdit` text as your value.

```
new_input = {metric.widget().objectName: metric.widget().text() for metric in items}
```

Then just send that data back to your dataframe.

```
for key, value in zip(new_input.keys(), new_input.values()):
    # You said the self.user_selection was a QModelIndex, so you can get your selected
    # row from there
    df.loc[self.user_selection.row(), key] = value
```

Then just send that dataframe to your class like you normally would to populate that table.